# Make React app route serve static folder

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I make the `{domainname}.com/public` route of my React app just serve the files in my `/public` directory? I am using `react-photo-gallery` which to my knowledge only allows the use of full urls (not the relative ones that are used inside components).

An example of this working would be that if I have a file `image.jpg` inside my `/public` folder, I could access it by going to `{domainname}.com/public/image.jpg`.

Comment: What have you tried? Give us an example to work with please

Comment: @BenRondeau I haven't tried anything yet. I added an example to the original question